# Changing structure of table depending on one colulmn in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, pivot, powerquery, transformation, divide

I am struggling recently with a Power Query transformation of a table. I have been trying diffrent tips from an Internet and I was getting close thanks to pivoting, but due to my lack of knowledge related to the PowerQuery tool I had to give up.
So I have a table in which a first column tells about a planned date for a given operation and an actual date. It looks like this:

**Current table's structure**
[image: Current table's structure]

I would like to restructure the table to delete first table and add to a header "Operation 1 Plan", "Operation 1 Actual" *et cetera*. So my desire is to accomplish a following situation:

**Desired table's structure**
[image: Desired table's structure]

I have been trying diffrent things, but still i couldn't manage do accomplish this. I hope someone will give me some hints on how to get this done. I would really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frequently with this kind of problem, you have to **unpivot** and **group** before getting your desired pivot results.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],

    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Type of Date", "Project"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//create the New column headers by merging
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Op Type", each Text.Combine({[Attribute], [Type of Date]}, " "), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"Type of Date", "Attribute"}),

//Group by "Project" and Pivot each grouped table
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Project"}, {
        {"Pivot", each Table.Pivot(_, List.Distinct(_[#"Op Type"]), "Op Type", "Value")}
        }),

//remove unneeded columns and expand the Pivoted column
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Project"}),
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Pivot", 
        {"Project", "Operation 1 Planned", "Operation 2 Planned", "Operation 3 Planned", "Operation 4 Planned", "Operation 1 Actual", "Operation 2 Actual", "Operation 3 Actual", "Operation 4 Actual"}, {"Project", "Operation 1 Planned", "Operation 2 Planned", "Operation 3 Planned", "Operation 4 Planned", "Operation 1 Actual", "Operation 2 Actual", "Operation 3 Actual", "Operation 4 Actual"}),

    //type the date columns
    dateCols = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Pivot"),1),
    dateTypes = List.Zip({dateCols,List.Repeat({type date}, List.Count(dateCols))}),
    typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Pivot",dateTypes)
in
    typed
```

**Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

***EDIT***
I noted the column name order in the results table was not what you had shown in your example. I added a few lines to the code so as to have the order correct.

Try this code instead:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],

    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Type of Date", "Project"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//create the New column headers by merging
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Op Type", each Text.Combine({[Attribute], [Type of Date]}, " "), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"Type of Date", "Attribute"}),
    //Group by "Project" and Pivot each grouped table

//create list of the Pivot Column Names in the desired order
//Extract a unique list of the names, then sort them => {op1Act, op1Plan, op2Act, op2Plan, ...}
//Split the list (List.Alternate) taking every other 
//    starting with either the first or second entry => {op1Act,op2Act,...}, and {op1Plan,op2Plan...}
//Zip those two lists together with the second list first; then Combine them into a single list
pivotColNames = List.Combine(
                    List.Zip({
                        List.Alternate(List.Sort(List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Op Type])),1,1),
                        List.Alternate(List.Sort(List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Op Type])),1,1,1)
                            })),

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Project"}, {
        {"Pivot", each Table.Pivot(_, pivotColNames, "Op Type", "Value")}
        }),

//remove unneeded columns and expand the Pivoted column
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Project"}),

//create column name list for the expanded pivot table, in the desired order
x = List.Combine({{"Project"},pivotColNames}),
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Pivot", 
        x,x),

    //type the date columns
    dateCols = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Pivot"),1),
    dateTypes = List.Zip({dateCols,List.Repeat({type date}, List.Count(dateCols))}),
    typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Pivot",dateTypes)
in
    typed
```

**Results with the new code**
[image]

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much. I have one more request. Could u give me a hint where I can get a knowledge on how to do this transformation? I have one more table to transform, so I am trying to follow your steps. Somehow i am struggling. So I would like to possess a knowledge for myself for a future about these fundamental transformation :)

Comment: @miasekk I've found MS documentation limited. I've read various blogs, primers, etc on line; and also reverse engineered answers by others.  I think you'll gain a lot by working through some of the online resources, but I'm not familiar enough to recommend more than a general search; and I don't think any single resource will give you all that you need. My main method of learning is by solving others problems, but it is a slow method.

Comment: @miasekk I noted the column order in the results table was not what you had shown in your example. I added a few lines to the code so as to have the order correct.

Comment: Thank you for additional care. I did it manually earlier, but this wasn't a problem, while my main question was huge challange for me, so I really appreciate your response, thank you!